# AWS Cloudfront: can I add different servers with different domains under only one distribution to save costs?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I want to use one CloudFront distribution in front of:

- mydomain.com --> points to a load balancer (website 1)
- blog.mydomain.com --> points to another load balancer (website 2)
- api.mydomain.com --> points to another load balancer (api server)
- s3 bucket --> images are stored

Is it possible to add Cloudfront (only one distribution) transparently, meaning without modifying any of the paths? How would that be done, in terms of how many origins and how many CNAMEs?

My aim is to save costs while enjoying of the best performance.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, that isn't possible.

But that doesn't really matter, because it would not result in a cost savings even if it were possible.  CloudFront distributions are free.  You only pay for requests and bandwidth, which would be no different whether you had one distribution or multiple distributions.